# How to allow multiple inputs when multiple buttons are selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jsfiddle application below:

http://jsfiddle.net/ybZvv/5/

If you open the jsfiddle, you will see a top control which contains "Answer" buttons. You will also see some letter buttons, a "True" button, and a "False" button.

The "True" and "False" buttons work perfectly, meaning that if the user clicks on "True" and then clicks on "False", it replaces the text input as you can't have an answer both "True" and "False".

This works for the same for the "Yes" and "No" buttons.

But there is a problem with the letter buttons. If you click on the letter buttons, you realise that you can click on multiple letter buttons which is fine, but the problem is that it replaces the text input for those letters which is incorrect. If multiple letter buttons are selected, then it should display the text inputs for all of those letter buttons, not replace the text input with the latest letter button selected.

I know the code below

`_oCurrAnswerContainer.html('');`

empties the container DIV, so it removes the inputs before creating a new one.

But I only want that to happen between the "True" and "False" buttons and "Yes" and "No" buttons. If you select mutliple letter buttons, it should not empty the container:

If buttons A, C and E are turned on, then text input A, C and E is shown, if E is then turned off, then text input for E is removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you wanna append. Why can't you make the code this way?

```
_oCurrAnswerContainer.html(_oCurrAnswerContainer.html() + '' + NewContents);
```

Append to it. I am not sure, as I don't understand the question.

Comment: I mean what I want to do is that if it is "True" or "False" button or if it is "Yes" or "No" button, then perform the `_oCurrAnswerContainer.html('');` code.

But if it is a letter button then perform the  `oCurrAnswerContainer.html(_oCurrAnswerContainer.html() + '' + NewContents);`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the solution is to continually inspect the selected letters, each time the user makes a selection or deselect a letter.

Example:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    var checkboxes = $('form > p > input:checkbox');

    // updates the text input with the selected values...
    var update = function() {
        var values = [];

        $('form > p > input:checked').each(function(idx, cb) {
            values.push($(this).val());
        });

        $('#foo').val(values.join(', '));
    };

    // count the number of selected items...
    var count = function() {
        var n = $("input:checked").length;
        $("div").text([n, 'box selected!'].join(' '));
    };

    // bind to the checkbox for clicks
    // update the input field
    // count the number of selected items
    $(checkboxes).on('click', function(e) {
        update();
        count();
    });

    update();

    count();
</script>
```

See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/3844611) for a working example